# Orphaned answers in migration rejections

Tags: discussion, bug, answers, migration-rejection

It appears that the following sequence results in orphaned answers:

1. Question is migrated from A.SE to B.SE.
2. An answer is posted on B.SE.
3. Question is closed on B.SE, which causes a "migration-rejection," effectively putting it back on A.SE.

The weird thing is that answers posted on A.SE follow the migration to B.SE *and* are retained when the migration is rejected and the question reverts to A.SE.  But answers posted on B.SE do not follow the question back to A.SE.

I'm not sure what the final disposition of these questions and answers are, especially if the question is left closed on A.SE.  But it *appears* that the answers posted while the question was on B.SE are going to be lost, in which case this seems like a bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is status-bydesign. In the 30 days that the rejected migration stub is present users can re-post their answer on A. After that period the OP's might find it on their profile or search for it with `deleted:yes`. That is something you as mod can do as well. Q/A pairs only migrate once, they are not kept in-sync. Maybe needs Animuson or a dev to confirm.